# How to pass the value to the dropdown list to be highlighted value on Edit template?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formview, dropdownbox

The label lblTempLib in the Form has the data coming from table A. This needs to be passed on to the dropdown list as the selected value to datasource in the edit template.

This is the object datasource for LibDS (markup):

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [LibName] FROM [tblBuilding]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:FormView ID="frmUpdateIncident" runat="server" DataSourceID="InciDetailDS" OnDataBound="frmUpdateIncident_DataBound">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLib" Text="Library:" CssClass="style_bold"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblTempLib" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Library")%>'Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Dropdownlist runat="server" ID="ddLib" DataTextField="LibName" DataSourceID="LibDS" >
        </asp:Dropdownlist>
```

VB.NET code:

```
Protected Sub frmUpdateIncident_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles frmUpdateIncident.DataBound
    Dim ddLib As DropDownList 
   Try
        If Page.FindControl("ddLibrary") IsNot Nothing Then
            ddLib = DirectCast(frmUpdateIncident.FindControl("ddLibrary"), DropDownList)
            ddLib.Items.FindByText(strLibName).Selected = True
        End If
 Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Does it throw errors, or not work correctly?

Comment: Yes. The error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when it hits ddLib.Items.... line.

Comment: It sounds like your DropDownList is not databound yet.  Can you use a debugger to check and see if `ddLib.Items` has anything in it when the FormView databound event fires?

Comment: Yes it has 3 items. This is my updated post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804703/nullreferenceexception-was-unhandled-by-the-user

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got it. Need to pass the index value to the dropdown SelectedIndex value as this property can get and set the value unlike SelectedValue.
strLibName is the value passed on by the previous form.

I hardcoded ddLib.SelectedIndex in here to test it but I will be fixing it by passing the list index value.
VB.Net Code:

```
    Protected Sub frmUpdateIncident_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles frmUpdateIncident.DataBound
    If frmUpdateIncident.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Edit Then
        Dim ddlib As DropDownList
        ddlib = DirectCast(frmUpdateIncident.FindControl("ddLibrary"), DropDownList)
        If ddLib IsNot Nothing Then
            If ddLib.Items.Count > 0 Then
                If strLibName IsNot Nothing Then
                    ddlib.SelectedIndex = 2
                    Dim strtest As String = ddlib.SelectedValue.Trim
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```