# NullReferenceException was unhandled by the user

Tags: vb.net, selectedvalue

I have this form on VS2012. This dropdownlist exists only in the Edit Template. I am trying to pass the value(strLibName) to this list as the selected value. This value is coming from the previous screen. I do get the count of 3 when I debug but sill it throws the error on the selected value line.I need some direction on how to get this problem resolved.

3:30pm - I don't get the error anymore, but the value is not being passed on to the control. The control ddLib still has the first value selected.

Thanks

VB.NET Code:

```
Protected Sub frmUpdateIncident_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles frmUpdateIncident.DataBound
    Dim ddLib As DropDownList
    ddLib = DirectCast(frmUpdateIncident.FindControl("ddLibrary"), DropDownList)
    If ddLib IsNot Nothing Then
        If ddLib.Items.Count > 0 Then
            If strLibName IsNot Nothing Then
                ddLib.SelectedValue = strLibName
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to find the control? It looks like you are on the same form. Can you simply get rid of ddLib and replace it with ddLibrary? To look into it as is, put a break point on the if and evaluate the value of the ddLib.

Comment: You have a nice set of `IsNot Nothing` conditions except in the last line. Presumably `.Value` is triggering the error because `strLibName` couldn't be found (you should have also included `If ddLib.Items.FindByText(strLibName) IsNot Nothing Then`). Actually, this is the only way in which your code can trigger a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Okay. The error is telling you that FindByText(strLibName) isn't finding a ListItem. When you try to set it's `.Value` you get the error. Check your value for strLibName as apparently it's incorrect.

Comment: I set the ddLib.SelectedValue = strLibName, now I don't get the error.However when the edit template is loaded it is not selected. When I looked at the source code, the control name is ddLibrary. Is that Why?

Comment: @SpectralGhost: This control is only in the Edit Template and not in the Item template. So I trying to find the contol. Does it make sense.

Comment: Could you post a portion of the ASPX page that contains the control frmUpdateIncident? (I deleted my answer because I was making assumptions)